# Not able to access data from Rest API-JIRA

Tags: jira-rest-api

I have created a atlassin account for testing the Jira rest api and created a project and  tickets under it.

I am able to access the projects but not the issues under it. Please find below for more info

[image]
[image]
[image]
Could someone please help me what permissions I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can access the issues using URL request for api as below

```
"https://site.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=updated>-90d&startAt="
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a permission issue, but you missed adding issueIdOrKey path parameter. JIRA attempts to identify the issue by the issueIdOrKey path parameter. This can be an issue id, or an issue key.

To get the issue details, you can use the following Jira Rest endpoint,

```
GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}
```

For your case it will be,

```
GET /rest/api/2/issue/BI-1
```

Comment: thanks @vishal. But I posted how I accessed the same as answer once I get how to do this